# Is it possible to use a Firestore transaction to update an object retrieved before the transaction?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Below is my code summarized, my question is quite simple, I actually already have the object `order` loaded before all this code, but I am afraid the update on this object will not be handled inside the transaction if I don't get it again inside it.

So my question is, do I have to retrieve again my `order` object inside the transaction?

```
try {
  await runTransaction(db, async (transaction) => {
    // First object to update
    const dailyCountSnap = await transaction.get(dailyCountRef);
    let dailyCount;
    if (dailyCountSnap.exists) {
      dailyCount = dailyCountSnap.data();
    } else {
      return Promise.reject(`ERROR: No daily count found`);
    }

    /* ... Code to update dailyCount ... */

    transaction.set(dailyCountRef, {...});

    // Second object to update
    const orderSnap = await transaction.get(orderRef);
    let order;
    if (orderSnap.exists) {
      order = orderSnap.data();
    } else {
      return Promise.reject(`ERROR: No order found`);
    }

    /* ... Code to update order ... */

    transaction.update(orderRef, {...});
  });
} catch (e) {
  functions.logger.error(e);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A transaction on Firestore only has context on data that was read within that transaction.

From the documentation on [optimistic concurrency controls](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/transaction-data-contention#data_contention_in_the_mobileweb_sdks):

> In the Mobile/Web SDKs, a transaction keeps track of all the documents you read inside the transaction.

and

> In the server client libraries, transactions place locks on the documents they read.

So if you write a document that you didn't read before, the write operation could be overwriting data in the document and not meet the isolation guarantee of the transaction. The SDK might even raise an error when you try this, although I didn't check that.